# .Net Core ELMAH functionality in another logger?

Tags: .net, logging, asp.net-core, log4net, elmah

Given that ELMAH will not soon be ported to .Net Core: https://github.com/elmah/Elmah/issues/407

Has anyone created a configuration in a ported logger (Log4Net?) that pulls in the HttpResponse Context information the way ELMAH does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ELMAH has now a [port](https://github.com/ElmahCore/ElmahCore) for core but this lacks of features from the orginal version. Better have a look at [StackExchange.Exceptional](https://github.com/NickCraver/StackExchange.Exceptional) it is inspired by ELMAH and availible for both old .net and new core .net.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: I don't think so.

To my knowledge, none of the providers for Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, include any information from the HTTP context (request, response, etc.). [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging) isn't web specific, why this behavior makes sense.

I've implemented ASP.NET Core middleware, which replicates ELMAH behavior by logging all uncaught exceptions to [elmah.io](https://elmah.io) (not ELMAH): https://github.com/elmahio/Elmah.Io.AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Elmah.Io.AspNetCore/ElmahIoMiddleware.cs.

If you want to know more about how to build error logging middleware, I wrote a blog posts as well: [Error Logging Middleware in ASP.NET Core](https://blog.elmah.io/error-logging-middleware-in-aspnetcore/). You could implement middleware like explained in the post, that logs to log4net or similar and include values from the HTTP response.